# How to Mock a Custom Type in Rspec-Puppet

Tags: mocking, tdd, puppet

I am able to test `custom types` using `rspec-puppet` due to implementing the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894798/how-to-test-custom-types-using-rspec-puppet) question.

However, I would like to avoid to create a symlink to the `custom folder` in every puppet-module by `mocking` `cystom types`.

The question is how to mock Custom Puppet Types in Rspec-Puppet.

I have found an [example](https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet/issues/102) regarding the mocking of a Custom Puppet `Function` but I am looking for an example to mock Puppet Custom `Types`.

**Puppet Code**

```
class vim::ubuntu::config {
  custom_multiple_files { 'line_numbers':
    ensure     => 'present',
    parent_dir => '/home',
    file_name  => '.vimrc',
    line       => 'set number';
  }
}
```

**Rspec-puppet code**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "vim::ubuntu::config" do
  ?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to go looking for examples on mocking is the collection of Puppet's own [unit tests](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/tree/master/spec/unit/type).

I'm not sure if there are an specialties that needs to be considered, but within Puppet's spec test, the mocking works like this:

```
let(:type) { Puppet::Type.type(:custom_file_line) }
it "should do whatever"
  type.stubs(:retrieve).returns <value>
  # perhaps also needed
  Puppet::Type.stubs(:type).with(:custom_file_line).returns(type)
```

From what I understand, this is [moccha](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/mock-framework-integration/mock-with-mocha) style mocking. In plain rspec, mocking/stubbing is a bit more [involved](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/README.md), which may be necessary with `rspec-puppet`.

Comment: I have tried to implement the examples, but the error `Invalid resource type custom_multiple_files` persists

Comment: Ah, I see. This is interesting additional information. I shall post another answer.

Comment: `let(:type) { Puppet::Type.type(:custom_multiple_files) }` results in: 2) vim::ubuntu::config
     Failure/Error: let(:type) { Puppet::Type.type(:custom_multiple_files) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `let' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0xb69aee88>
     # ./spec/classes/ubuntu_config_spec.rb:12

Comment: I've since tinkered with `rspec-puppet` a bit and stubbing a type for a test does not seem to be possible in a way as simple as I had in mind. The reason is likely the mucking that `rspec-puppet` is doing with the actual `rspec` framework. Bottom line is, even if it's possible to stub the type away, I suspect that the usual route of symlinking the respective module(s) into `spec/fixtures` is too much easier to pass up ;-)