# How to rspec test a Puppet class when a parameter needs a resource reference

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

This may be a simple matter of mocking a resource, but...

```
class myclass (
  String stringParam,
  Integer intParam,
  File fileParam
) {
 # do some things
 $path = fileParam['title']
 $mode = fileParam['mode']
 # do some more things
 }
```

Now I want to write an rspec-puppet test for this class. How do I either create or mock a File resource and get it into the catalog that rspec-puppet uses, so that I can reference it?

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894798/how-to-test-custom-types-using-rspec-puppet) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060142/how-to-mock-a-custom-type-in-rspec-puppet) got me partway there, but everything I've tried has led to myClass complaining that it's being passed a string instead of a file reference.

```
...
let(:params) {{
  :stringParam => 'Here is my string',
  :intParam    => 238,
  :fileParam   => *??????,*
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really much support in rspec-puppet for this, as a class test parameters list is generated from the `:params` assuming only strings (or nested hashes/arrays etc. containing strings) or a couple of permitted symbol values used almost literally, `:undef` and `:default`. It doesn't have a way of passing in resource references.

A workaround exists that lets you put literal content into a manifest though, by passing an object that responds to the `inspect` method. For example, in your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
class ResourceReference
  def initialize(ref)
    @ref = ref
  end

  def inspect
    @ref
  end
end
```

And then in your spec:

```
let(:params) {{
  :stringParam => 'Here is my string',
  :intParam    => 238,
  :fileParam   => ResourceReference.new("File[/etc/foo]"),
}}
```

rspec-puppet will call the `inspect` method on the `ResourceReference` object which returns the string you've passed in. This should be placed in the manifest unchanged.

(This was originally used as a workaround for `undef`, which can now be passed as `:undef`.)

As an aside, you can set `let(:pre_condition) { "..." }` to add literal content to the test manifest before the generated `class { ... }`, but I don't think there's a way to use that here.

I'd strongly recommend filing a feature request against rspec-puppet.

Comment: If you use let(:pre-condition) to instantiate some resources, and then this workaround to get references to them, be careful (as always) about evaluation order; you can't count on the attributes of a resource being present until the resource has been required.